# Peptides neither produced by the ribosome or the non-ribosomal peptide synthase complexes

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, amino-acids, ribosome

I read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonribosomal_peptide):

> While there exist a wide range of peptides that are not synthesized by
>   ribosomes, the term nonribosomal peptide typically refers to a very
>   specific set of these as discussed in this article.

I was wondering what peptides are being referred to. I can only think of synthetically produced peptides. I can not find any source for other peptides not produced either by the ribosome or by the non-ribosomal peptide synthases described.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One peptide that comes to mind is the metabolically important reducing tripeptide [**glutathione**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutathione) — γ-L-Glutamyl-L-cysteinylglycine:

[image: structure of glutathione]

This is [synthesized](https://www.genome.jp/kegg/pathway/map/map00480.html) from cysteine, glutamate and glycine by reactions catalysed by glutamate cysteine ligase and glutathione synthase:

[image: glutathione synthesis]

*Synthesis of glutathione (GSH) — two subunits of glutamate cysteine ligase (GCL) are shown*

Other examples may involve amino acids not specified by the genetic code which have particular roles in metabolism. For example, [**taurine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurine), which has a sulphonic — rather than a carboxylic — acid group, can be [metabolized](https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?map=map00430&show_description=show) to the dipeptide [γ-Glutamyltaurine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutaurine) which may have a role in the brain.

These two examples relate to L-amino acids, albeit with a peptide bond between the side-chain glutamyl carboxyl group rather than the α-carboxyl group. However a D-amino acid dipeptide, *D-alanyl-D-alanine*, synthesized in the reaction catalysed by D-alanine-D-alanine ligase, is a [precursor of bacterial peptidoglycan synthesis](https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?map=map00473&show_description=show).

All the examples given have in common the fact that the peptides are very short (di- or tri-peptides) and can be synthesized in reactions requiring one or two specialized enzymes. Bacterial antibiotics synthesized by the non-ribosomal peptide complex tend to be appreciably larger, requiring repeated formation of peptide bonds.